# 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' Error

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to do a basic update of db context. I am using mvc4

this is what i have in my controller :

```
context.Entry<Rental>(rental);
context.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

i have a dbcontext class with this definition:

```
T IDAContext.Entry<T>(T entity)
{
     return Set<T>().Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

and finally in my interface

```
T Entry<T>(T entity) where T : class;
```

i am getting this error

> 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

also getting

> The name 'EntityState' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: What is the data type of the variable `context`?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework or Linq-To-Sql?

Comment: context = new DAContext();

Comment: also is this syntax correct to update a record: return Set<T>().Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;   ??

Answer (score 0):

my psychic debugging powers tell me that even though `context` was declared as a `DbSet`, you instantiated it as some class derived from `DbSet` that you expect to have an `Entry()` method

If that's the case, then you should either declare `context` to be the derived type in the first place, or you should cast it to the derived type

```
((InsertDerivedTypeHere)context).Entry<Rental>(rental);
```

Comment: what do you mean? my context is as you said, its declared as context = new DAContext();